# Enterprise Level Monitoring Solution

Tags: performance-monitoring

My company is currently looking to replace our current solution used for monitoring our web-based enterprise solutions for both up-time and performance.  Please note this is not intended to be a network monitoring-type solution (internally we currently use Nagios).  If anyone has a provider that they have had a positive experience with, it would be much appreciated.

Here is a list of our requirements:

•   Must have a large number of probes/agents around the globe to be representative of our customer base
•   Must have a flexible scripting capability to automate multi-step user actions
•   24 hour a day monitoring
•   Flexible alerting system
•   Report generation capability
•   Mimic browser specific monitoring (optional, not a must-have)

Comment: I wrote an anser but then after re-reading noticed you do not want a proper monitoring solution but reccomendations for a monitoring provider- is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently going through the same process and I am interested to hear what others say.  There are a few products we are looking at that might be able to help you discern which way to go.

- Zabbix
- Zenoss
- EM7 by ScienceLogic

We are looking to these solutions to meet the bottom 5 requirements you mention.

Your first requirement of global monitors would be better met through a company like Gomez which has distributed nodes and can give you a better picture of global performance.  For my implementation, we have separated out our monitoring categories into Synthetic Monitors and End-User Synthetic Monitors.

The reason why we have split these up into two categories is because End-User Synthetic Monitors are great at running web transactions but they are difficult (and expensive) to implement in a way which monitors your load balanced (redundant) servers or services.

Synthetic Monitors are able to complete web transactions and test different layers of the stack (db, app servers, web, network, disk...) while End-User Synthetic tests overall uptime and availability for the users by mimicking end-user browsers geographically distributed.

Hope this helps and look forward to hearing others thoughts.

Comment: I'm hoping to see other people's experiences, but your answer also included some good pointers to assist in my search.